# Import Orange 2.7 canvas in Orange 3

Tags: orange

I have a saved canvas I created in Orange 2.7. I just installed Orange 3 and opening the old canvas gives multiple "UnknownWidgetDefinition" errors. I gather that the naming/location of some widgets has changed between versions. Is there a way to import the old canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the naming has changed, also the individual widget settings and layouts are completely different. Some Orange 2 widgets are not even available in Orange 3 yet, or have been consolidated into other ones. I'm afraid Orange 2 workflows are just not compatible with Orange 3.